# Difference between fft points and fft in vector

Tags: matlab, vector, fft

Given a vector `X` of length `L`, what is the difference between `fft(X)` and `fft(X,L)`?

Does it mean we are taking the `fft` on `L` points when using `fft(X)` and the `fft` of vector `L` when doing `fft(X,L)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the documentation on `fft`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html):

> `Y = fft(X)` computes the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of `X` using a fast Fourier transform (FFT) algorithm.
>
> If `X` is a vector, then `fft(X)` returns the Fourier transform of the vector.
>
> `Y = fft(X,n)` returns the `n`-point DFT. If no value is specified, `Y` is the same size as `X`.
>
> If `X` is a vector and the length of `X` is less than `n`, then `X` is padded with trailing zeros to length `n`.
>
> If `X` is a vector and the length of `X` is greater than `n`, then `X` is truncated to length `n`.

Meaning that in case you have a vector `X` of length `L`, `fft(X)` and `fft(X,L)` are **equivalent**.

The interesting bit comes when you call `fft(X,n)` with `n~=L`.

- If `n<L` your input vector `X` will be trucated, i.e. you will use less measurements and get a shorted Fourier sequence.
- If `n=L`; discussed above
- If `n>L` your vector `X` is zero-padded:  `X = [X zeros(L-n,1)]` (for a row vector `X`). What this will do is interpolation in the frequency domain. This is most easily seen from the formulae [at the bottom of the documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html?s_tid=doc_ta#buuutyt-5):

[image]

if we increase `n`, we get a longer vector `Y`. However, since you padded zeros, and not a continuation of the signal, its Fourier transform will be an *interpolation*  between frequencies. Normally you'd have the frequencies as given by `W(n)` running from your sampling frequency, `f_s` all the way up to `f_n = Nyquist/2` in `L` steps, i.e. as many data points as you have: `linspace(F_s,f_n,L)`. What you are doing when zero padding is putting *more* points into the same space: `linspace(F_s,f_n,n)`, without adding information.

Comment: Thank you so much, How can we get  fft in L-point and fft with L vector? OR that is similar ?

Comment: @New_student to get the FFT in `L` points, use `fft(X,L)`, as I wrote. `L` is not a vector, rather a "Nonnegative integer scalar" as per the documentation. I.e., `L` is a **number** which corresponds to the amount of points the output vector should have. Taking the Fourier transform of that point is rather pointless.

Comment: OK, got it. but what's about if I want to get the FFT with vector L, support L = 1 : 128. can I use for example fft(X,1:L) ?

Comment: @New_student no. You'd have to do `fft(x,L)` with `L`  integer. This assumes a unit step between the points in `x`. Basically your "support vector" will have `N` evenly distributed points (otherwise things get way complicated), i.e. use `fft(x,N)` and then treat the step between the transformed values as the step size defined in your support vector. Read the documentation on `fft`, they do have examples for that.